# Is it a good practice to maintain web services for both web application and mobile application in the same project?

Tags: spring, web-services, architecture

So far I've been developing applications where I included services for both web and mobile applications in the single spring boot application where I've used different packages for different clients. But here The problems I faced are like, Since both clients are pointing to the same app in same server, Maintenance became difficult for me for e.g. When I update any service in Mobile part, whole code has deployed and things like this.

I do know it's more generic question.
But here the point in my question is, Is it really a good practice to provide APIs for both web and mobile client from the single application in the Server? Suggest me some good references

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR is, as usual, "it depends" - on size, complexity, team structure and other factors.

Keep going with everything in a single project until a compelling reason to do otherwise emerges.